# CSS - flexbox issue

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Hello I am trying to have three groups of three buttons with each group appearing on a separate line, I managed to achieve this by just grouping them up with divs, however when i use flexbox to position the buttons in the center of the page, all the buttons appear on one line. Is there a way i could use flexbox for my positioning and still be able to have the buttons on separate lines?

```css
html,body{ 
 margin:0; 
 padding:0; 
 height:100%; 
 width:100%; 
 overflow: hidden;
}
.options{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 
}
.options a{
 color: inherit;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="home.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="options">
  <div class="one">
  <button><a href="#">Maths</a></button>
  <button><a href="#">Computer Science</a></button>
  <button><a href="#">Physics</a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  <button><a href="#">Chemistry</a></button>
  <button><a href="#">Biology</a></button>
  <button><a href="#">Business Studies</a></button>
  </div>
  <div class="three">
  <button><a href="#">Philosophy</a></button>
  <button><a href="#">Geography</a></button>
  <button><a href="#">History</a></button>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.options {flex-direction: column}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this

```
flex-flow:column;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.options{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    flex-direction: column;

}
```

exemple : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-flow.asp